# Bootstrap v3 hidden-* error at the specific breakpoint widths

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Visit the following codepen in Chrome or Firefox, and get your screen width to be exactly 767px, 991px, or 1199px (note these widths are right at -1px bootstrap's breakpoints)
https://codepen.io/cpj22/pen/WVoKON

This div should be hidden, but it is visible at those exact screen widths. The relevant html:

```
<div class="row hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        this should always be hidden on all device widths!
    </div>
</div>
```

At all other screen widths, this div is completely hidden as it should be.

Bootstrap v3.4.1, the latest v3. I hope I'm missing something, as this is occurring in our app and thus for users who happen to set their screen/browser window to any of these specific pixel widths, they see *very* incorrect views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in Bootstrap 4. Put these lines in your custom stylesheet so there is 0.02 px space between the breakpoints.

```
@media (max-width:767.98px) {
    .hidden-xs {
        display:none!important
    }
}
@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:991.98px) {
    .hidden-sm {
        display:none!important
    }
}
@media (min-width:992px) and (max-width:1199.98px) {
    .hidden-md {
        display:none!important
    }
}
@media (min-width:1200px) {
    .hidden-lg {
        display:none!important
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, do you have a source? I'm interested to read about what/why/how

Comment: After downloading the Bootstrap 4.3 files on https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/download/ you may have a look in the bootstrap-grid.css file. For detailed info click on Layout in the left column of that page.